# Apache PIG: apply LIMIT only if parameter is > 0

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How can I achieve the following in PIG, within a `foreach`:

```
REL = foreach RELS {
 if ( cnt == 0 )
 limited_result = NULL/Empty;
 else
 limited_result = LIMIT results cnt ;

 generate limited_result.some_field;
}
```

I cannot use `LIMIT`, since it validates that the 'cnt' is bigger than 0;
I've tried to use a `SPLIT`, but apparently it isn't supported within `foreach`.

Comment: What is the schema of your data?

Comment: It's a little complex to post here, is it relevant in this case?

Answer (score 2):

How about `FILTER`ing before your `FOREACH`?

```
REL = foreach (filter RELS by cnt > 0) {
 limited_result = LIMIT results cnt ;
 generate limited_result.some_field;
}
```

If you still need the records where `cnt` is 0, you could `SPLIT` first and then generate an empty bag when `cnt` is 0:

```
split RELS into ZERO if cnt == 0, NONZERO if cnt > 0;

NZ_LIM = foreach NONZERO {
 result = LIMIT results cnt ;
 generate limited_result.some_field;
}
Z_LIM = foreach ZERO generate {} as some_field;

REL = union NZ_LIM, Z_LIM;
```

Comment: Interesting, gonna check that out. BTW, I didn't know that foreach could handle such syntax. I'm doing something a little more complicated anyway, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm hitting a strange PIG error: `Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. ... at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.ReadScalars.exec(ReadScalars.java:111)
... at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLimit.getNext(POLimit.java:95)  ` Problem is I can't really see the relatin between the 1st and 2nd rows that pig shows in the error log.

Comment: Hard to say, not knowing what your data looks like.  But this might point you in the right direction: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2134.

Comment: The `SPLIT` doesn't guarantee exactly cnt results. if two tuples have same cnt, the `SPLIT` won't be as accurate as an order/limit. But it is a useful workaround.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the `SPLIT` not being accurate when two tuples have the same `cnt`.  BTW, I edited it because it should have been `>` rather than `>=`.